# GWMI Query hangs PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

I have a few servers that are flaky and cause my PowerShell scripts to hang. Does anyone know of a way I can script in some type of timeout or equivalent?

The query that is causing me issues in the script and from the PowerShell console is:
gwmi win32_computersystem -ComputerName $server | select numberofprocessors,domain,manufacturer,model,totalphysicalmemory

The query just hangs. It is definitely an issue on the server, but I need to have the script continue when it does not get a response within X amount of time.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I've often found that hanging WMI queries that never timeout with PowerShell often work just fine via a .NET application. In fact, in my environment right now, about 10% of the servers will cause my PowerShell script to hang when querying Win32_Group or Win32_Services but the C# app does not have any issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can start the query as a job then use `Wait-Job` to wait until the job completes or a timeout is reached. The timeout value is in seconds. An example:

```
 $job = gwmi win32_computersystem -ComputerName $server -AsJob | Wait-Job -Timeout 30
 if ($job.State -ne 'Completed') {
     Write-Host "'$server' timed out after 30 seconds."
     return
 }
 $results = $job | Receive-Job | select numberofprocessors,domain,manufacturer,model,totalphysicalmemory
```